# Can't add a second website (multiple domains) on a VPS with Apache 2.2

Tags: apache2

I have a VPS with a website (www.domain1.com) smoothly running on it (Ubuntu 10.04, Apache 2.2, RoR, Passenger, mysql). I now need to get a second website running (www.domain2.com). But the website is not displayed after I did all the setup.

I added in apache2/sites-enabled/domain2.com

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  ServerAdmin email@test.com
  ServerName  www.domain2.com
  ServerAlias domain2.com

  DirectoryIndex index.html
  DocumentRoot /home/user/public_html/domain2.com/current/public

  LogLevel debug
  ErrorLog  /home/user/public_html/domain2.com/current/log/error.log
  CustomLog /home/user/public_html/domain2.com/current/log/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

This is basically the same as for domain1, just the domain name is different. The code of domain2 is in /home/user/public_html/domain2.com/current/

httpd.conf is empty (I think this is ok for Apache 2.2), the relevant part of apache2.conf is:

```
ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"

# Include generic snippets of statements
Include /etc/apache2/conf.d/

# Include the virtual host configurations:
Include /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/

ServerName 23.42.74.241

LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.9/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.9
PassengerRuby /usr/local/bin/ruby

PassengerDefaultUser user
```

/etc/apache2/conf.d/servername.conf is:

```
ServerName general
```

I'm not sure if this name ("general") is relevant at all...

After a sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart domain1.com still workes perfectly, domain2 not. DNS settings are the same for domain1 and domain2, a test gives me the right DNS server for domain2. The only error using www.dns-info.cz is:

attendance of NS records in the zone (info) ERROR
The zone does not contain any NS record although at least one name server returns authoritative data for this domain name. The zone must contain the same NS records as parent server.

I'm not sure if this error is directly connected to the problem, this is just for your information. Does anybody know how to resolve this issue?